# Adding a branch template using code does not copy layout/rendering data, why/how to fix?

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore-branch-templates

I have a branch template that inherits from a standard template. If I add renderings to the branch template and add to Sitecore using the menu functions (insert -> insert from template -> etc) the renderings, etc. appear as expected, i.e. exactly as they are in the branch template. Good as I expected.

The problems though arise when I try and add a branch template in code. Doing it this way seems to ignore any renderings in the branch template. The renderings shown are those in the standard template only. I've tried moving all the rendering data into the branch template but this results in no layout data being sent to the the newly created item. I create the item thus:

```cs
Item parent = SitecoreService.Database.GetItem(parentPath);
if (parent == null)
   throw new NullReferenceException("Cannot load item to act as parent from path: " + parentPath);

Item branchItem = SitecoreService.Database.GetItem(new ID(branchTemplateId));
branchItem.Fields.ReadAll();
//BranchItem branch = SitecoreService.Database.GetItem(new ID(branchTemplateId));
if (branchItem == null)
   throw new ApplicationException("Failed ot find template branch with the id:" + branchTemplateId);

Item itemFromBranch = parent.Add(itemName, new BranchItem(branchItem));
```

I've actually attempted several variation of the above (using implicit cast, adding and removing `ReadAll` from the `Fields`, etc.).

The rendering field is blank when created though code, when created though the menu it's "Raw" value is thus:

```xml
<r  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><d id="{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}" l="{9FCEC8D8-9676-4C12-A9E2-72E0EAD07B5B}"><r ds="{CE6EB528-B937-4B0F-9897-B26C4EF8AFEE}" id="{89E00DE8-774D-4584-8002-9C28E8099711}" par="" ph="header" uid="{9AAB1306-BF20-44E7-B83C-26DA7173DC9C}" /><r ds="{A046699C-5FDF-468F-8FDF-3E9FAB0A35D0}" id="{19DD096B-F95E-46C0-A290-12A4B04E910C}" par="" ph="header" uid="{EB1AEB53-E001-42B3-BDFD-7570817E3B59}" /><r id="{7DE1675E-B511-4879-9003-7AC46E83A07B}" ph="header" uid="{4CF3F325-258D-4749-9CE0-61B4675692E1}" /><r id="{A00BE211-B0E0-462A-B377-BEBFF753D250}" ph="header" uid="{EC988DBC-AE99-44A9-BE4A-153B9C02C9F7}" /><r ds="{5A6B1B00-6941-44BB-9418-07784826E5AF}" id="{784DE1DD-B3FB-4A2D-BF4D-7CF9DDEA8C49}" par="" ph="footer" uid="{948F0EC3-DB97-47E8-8C06-4FACC2FBF7DC}" /></d></r>
```

What am I missing here?

---

Tried Mareks' suggestion below, but appears to do the same:

```
Item parent = SitecoreService.Database.GetItem(parentPath);
if (parent == null)
    throw new NullReferenceException("Cannot load item to act as parent from path: " + parentPath);

BranchItem branchItem = SitecoreService.Database.GetItem(new ID(branchTemplateId));

if (branchItem == null)
     throw new ApplicationException("Failed ot find template branch with the id:" + branchTemplateId);


Item itemFromBranch = Context.Workflow.AddItem(itemName, branchItem, parent);
```

Answer (score 2):

UI command uses `Workflow.AddItem` method.

Try code below:

```cs
Item branchItem = (BranchItem)SitecoreService.Database.GetItem(new ID(branchTemplateId));
if (branchItem == null)
    throw new ApplicationException("Failed ot find template branch with the id:" + branchTemplateId);

Context.Workflow.AddItem(itemName, branchItem, parent);
```

Comment: I thought you had it here, but it doesn't appear to make any difference. I'm guessing you reflected this out of the site core dll's. Could you point me at the code that does the above?

Comment: Check `Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.AddFromTemplate.Execute()` method.

Comment: Which version of Sitecore do you use? Do you have multiple languages? Do you try to add new branch using `en` language?

Comment: sitecore 8. I do have multiple languages. I will try ensuring the en version now.

Comment: Nope still nothing. I'm missing something here. I'm copying the code in the pipelines to the letter now...

Comment: Maybe the problem is with access rights? Can you try to use SecurityDisabler?

Comment: Already doing that. It's just in the method above the one shown.

Comment: I give in, **thanks for your help**. I'm just going to do a hacky solution using templates. Not ideal but I've wasted days trying to figure this out now to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following

```
var branchpath = "your/branch/template/path";

using (new SecurityDisabler())
{
   var masterDb = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");

   Item parentItem = masterDb.Items["path/to/parent/item/here"];

   BranchItem template = masterDb.GetItem(branchpath);

   parentItem.Add("YourItemName", template);

}
```

Thanks

Comment: How does this vary from my original code? You just appear to be selecting the parentItem in a slightly different manner. This smells of a random guess. Do you know this actually addresses the issue?

Comment: Nothing is different except for the security disabler part. I've once used this piece of code on a prototype project which worked for me. Just wanted to share it. :) It was on Sitecore 7.2

Comment: Ah right, I already have a security disabler, it's just not in the code in this question. When you used this did it apply the branch renderings? i.e. not those from the template but those in the branch?

Comment: Yes, the rendering appears even if I configured them on the branch template.